# proving strong duality from Farkas

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am confused about a step in showing how the Farkas Lemma (really, Gale's theorem) can be used to prove strong duality in linear programming.
Consider the following duality pair of LPs:

[image]

By weak duality, we only need to show that
\begin{align}
 \exists(x,y) :
    \begin{cases}
      Ax\leq b,\; x\geq0\\
      A^\top y \geq c,\; y\geq0\\
      c^\top x\geq b^\top y.
    \end{cases}
  \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

Then we have
\begin{align*}
    &\iff
    \exists(x,y) :
    \begin{cases}
      Ax\leq b,\; x\geq0\\
      A^\top y \geq c,\; y\geq0\\
      c^\top x\geq b^\top y.
    \end{cases} &(\text{weak duality})\\
    &\iff \exists(x,y) :
    \begin{cases}
      {
      \begin{bmatrix}
        A & 0\\
        -I & 0\\
        0 & -A^\top\\
        0 & -I\\
        -c^\top & b^\top
      \end{bmatrix}
      }
      {\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}} \leq {\begin{bmatrix} b\\0\\-c\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}}
    \end{cases},\;\;x\geq0,\;\;y\geq0\\
    &\iff
    \not\exists
    \begin{bmatrix}
      s\\
      t\\
      u\\
      v\\
      w
    \end{bmatrix}
    :
    \begin{cases}
      \begin{bmatrix}
        s\\t\\u\\v\\w
      \end{bmatrix}\geq0,\;
      \begin{bmatrix}
        s\\t\\u\\v\\w
      \end{bmatrix}^\top
      \begin{bmatrix}
        A & 0\\
        -I & 0\\
        0 & -A^\top\\
        0 & -I\\
        -c^\top & b^\top
      \end{bmatrix}=0,\;
      \begin{bmatrix}
        s\\t\\u\\v\\w
      \end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} b\\0\\-c\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} < 0
    \end{cases} & (\text{Farkas/Gale})\\
    &\iff
    \not\exists
    \begin{bmatrix}
      s\\t\\u\\v\\w
    \end{bmatrix}\geq0
    :
    \begin{cases}
      s^\top A - t^\top -w c^\top = 0_n^\top      &\iff s^\top A -w c^\top \geq 0_n^\top\\
      -u^\top A^\top - v^\top +wb^\top = 0_m^\top &\iff -u^\top A^\top +wb^\top \geq 0_m^\top\\
      s^\top b -u^\top c < 0                      &\iff b^\top s < c^\top u
    \end{cases}\\
    &\iff
    \not\exists
    \begin{bmatrix}
      s\\u\\w
    \end{bmatrix}\geq0
    :
    \begin{cases}
      A^\top s \geq wc\\
      A u \leq wb\\
      b^\top s < c^\top u
    \end{cases}\\
  &\color{red}{\iff}
    \not\exists
    \begin{bmatrix}
      s\\u
    \end{bmatrix}\geq0
    :
    \begin{cases}
      A^\top s \geq 0\\
      A u \leq 0\\
      b^\top s < c^\top u
    \end{cases} &(\text{weak duality})\tag{$**$}\\
    &\iff
    \left\{
      \left\{A^\top s\geq 0,\; Au\leq 0,\; s\geq0,\;u\geq0 \right\}
    \implies b^\top s \geq c^\top u \right\}
  \end{align*}
and finally $(***)$, assuming that $Au\leq0,A^\top s\geq0, s\geq0, u\geq0$ we have
\begin{align*}
b^\top s - c^\top u \geq (Ax)^\top s - (A^\top y)^\top u = x^\top A^\top s - y^\top Au \geq 0-0=0
\end{align*}

The proof is taken from p.17 of [these](http://www-oldurls.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/lect/pclect/notes2013/ch1-4.pdf) notes.
I don't understand how $(**)$ and $(***)$ are used.
Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Inspiration from [these](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ewayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/LinearProgrammingII.pdf) notes.

---

For $(**)$, we can take $w=0$ or $w>0$. If $w>0$, then we can scale $s'=s/w$, $x'=x/w$ so that we have the condition to prove is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\exists(x',y')\geq0:
\begin{cases}
  A^\top s'\geq c\\Ax' \leq b\\
  b^\top y' < c^\top x'
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which by weak duality on the ``prime'' system (e.g., $b^\top y'\geq c^\top x'$) gives a contradiction.
Hence $w\equiv0$.

For $(***)$, we just have to show that when $w\equiv0$, we can always find $s,u\geq0$ such that $b^\top s\geq c^\top u$.
Assuming that the feasible regions of the LPs P and D are nonempty, we know by weak duality that there's an original feasible pair $(x^*,y^*)$ such that the last line holds, meaning that $c^\top x^*\geq b^\top y^*$, and we're done.